# Traversing Multiple Levels of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, flask, get

Let's say there's a schedules dictionary:

```
schedules = {
        "employees": {
            "1":{
                "2018":{
                    "aug":{
                        "1": {"day": 1, "start": "08:00h"},
                        "2": {"day": 1, "start": "08:00h"}
                    },
                    "sep":{
                        "1": {"day": 1, "start": "08:00h"},
                        "2": {"day": 1, "start": "08:00h"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And there is a Flask route that is supposed to grab a specific month's schedule, for example getting a GET request with request.args.get("months") = "aug" . I have tried the following:

```
 sel_schedule = {}
    for employees, employee in schedules.items():
                for year, month in employee.items():
                    if month == request.args.get("months"):
                        sel_schedule = sel_schedule.update(month)
                        return render_template("scheduleinfo.html", sched = sel_schedule)
```

Yet, the whole dictionary is returned for some reason. What exactly is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few layers of the dictionary. You did not iterate over all the keys under `'employees'` (the `"1"`) and you did not iterate over all the months. This is what you can do:

```
for employees, employee in schedules.items():
    for num, schedule in employee.items():
        for year, months in schedule.items():
            for month in months:
                if month == request.args.get("months"):
                    sel_schedule.update(months[month])
                    return render_template("scheduleinfo.html", sched = sel_schedule)
```